# Why do English transliterations of Arabic names have so many Qs in them?

Tags: english, arabic, transliteration, velar

I remember when the Muslim holy book was the Koran when I was in middle school, but now it's the Quran. But it's always been Qatar and Iraq (but still Kuwait.)
Who decided that 'Q' was going to be represent that sound instead of 'K', and why?

Comment: [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_stop) and [q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_uvular_stop) are distinct [consonants in Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_phonology#Consonants)

Comment: In many countries/languages it is actually Irak and often it still is Koran or Katar (check the left column on Wikipedia). For common names one often does not use the scientific transliteration.

Comment: Should we throw Spanish transliterations using 'C' into the mix? 

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, different languages are different. The question is specifically about transliterations into English.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The question is about *transliterations*. In those languages the scientific transliterations *also do* distinguish k and q, there is no difference. Anyway, it was a remark, not an answer.

Comment: @VladimirF The question is about transliterations _into English_. It's right there in the title.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The transliteration rules are mostly universal. My only point is that for common names other customary rules are often used. Now mainly in other languges. In the past, as the question itself hints, [even in English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Koran%2C+Kuran%2C+Quran&case_insensitive=on&corpus=15&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CKoran%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BKoran%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bkoran%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CKuran%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BKuran%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bkuran%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BKURAN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQuran%3B%2Cc0). I really don't get what you are after.

Comment: I recall someone calculated that there were over 100 valid English transliterations of "Gaddafi / Qadhafi / Gathafi / Qadhdhāfī / etc.".

Comment: Am I alone in finding the issue of O vs U (between Koran and Qur'an) far more interesting than the issue of K vs Q?

Answer (score 85):

In Arabic, in fact, they've always been separate sounds! The sound we write "K" is spelled with the letter ك in Arabic, and is pronounced a little bit further forward in the mouth; the sound we write "Q" is spelled with the letter ق and pronounced a little bit farther back. In phonetic terms, "K" is a *velar* sound, and "Q" is a *uvular* sound.

English doesn't distinguish between these two different sounds. But since we've got a spare letter lying around—the English letter "Q" is actually related to the Arabic letter ق, if you go back far enough!—it's become conventional to separate them in writing. "Kuwait" is spelled with a ك, so it gets a "K"; "Qatar" is spelled with a ق, so it gets a "Q". The "Qur'an", similarly, has a ق in it.

Nowadays, by the way, the letter "Q" has started to be associated with Arabic in particular, since it shows up significantly more there than in English. So in pop culture, you'll sometimes see names like "Hakeem" respelled to "Haqim"—even though the original Arabic has a ك in it! Linguistically, this is called *hypercorrection*, and it's the same reason you'll see words like "forté" with an *é*: English-speakers associate the acute accent with Romance loans (café, fiancé, résumé), but it has no special meaning in English, so it sometimes gets inserted where it doesn't actually belong (the original Italian word is simply *forte*).

Comment: Which letter Quran/Koran has in Arabic, and why was the change?

Comment: @svavil In Arabic, *al-Qurʼān* is written القرآن — to me that looks closer to a ق Q than to a ك K, but I'm no expert.

Comment: @svavil Note that some of the early transliterators were French, not English, and therefore mapped Arabic vowel sounds onto French ones, which are not the same as English. Also "qu" in English represents the "kw" sound, not "k" followed by a long vowel, though in French "qu" does represent the "k" sound . So "Koran" not a literal transliteration, but would have given a better idea of the sound to English speakers in the era before sound recording and radio/TV.

Comment: Don't you mean hyperforeignism?

Comment: @Nardog it's both - hyperforeignism is a specific type of hypercorrection

Comment: @walen: yes, you are right, it's a ق Q. [Arabic consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet) take up to four variant shapes, depending on whether they are isolated, or in initial/medial/final position. ق is the isolated shape, whereas the shape in القرآن is medial, since it is connected to the previous l (to the right) and the following r (to the left).

Comment: @Will They certainly overlap, but I don't think one is a complete subset of the other. Doesn't hypercorrection always refer to inadvertent overapplication while hyperforeignism can mean a stylistic choice too? I don't think one is trying to correct anything and overapplying it when one writes *forté* or *afficioñado*.

Comment: @Nardog I think of "forté" as overapplying the rule "`/ej/` in Romance borrowings is spelled 'é', especially word-finally" (café, résumé, naïveté, né, fiancé). Similarly "afficioñado" is overapplying the rule "non-initial 'n' in Spanish words has a tilde over it" (señor, Español, piñata, el niño).

Comment: @Draconis Do people do that by accident rather than as a stylistic choice? Even "Haqim"?

Comment: @Nardog I'm not sure; I've definitely seen "forté" by accident, and I'm assuming the others are similarly accidental.

Comment: @Nardog according to Wikipedia, foreignisms which are deliberately misapplied as a stylistic choice knowing they wouldn't be used in the originating language aren't strictly classified as hyperforeignisms. I'm willing to believe that the page overstates the lingusitic consensus as to this terminology though.

Comment: I question whether "afficioñado" (with the tilde) is actually used. When I Google it, the only significant result is _this_ SE question.

Comment: I also have never heard of "afficioñado"

Comment: @JustinLardinois I may have imagined that one; is there an example you'd suggest instead?

Comment: @Draconis thought about it for 15 minutes and no, I don't. Also _forte_ is an interesting case because it's from French, where it's pronounced _fort_. _Forté_ emphasizes the way we usually pronounce it in English, which is as if it was a Spanish word.

Comment: "but it has no special meaning in English" It communicates that the e is not silent. See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mol%C3%A9 "Similarly "afficioñado" is overapplying the rule "non-initial 'n' in Spanish words has a tilde over it" By "rule", do you mean "perceived rule"?

Comment: @Acccumulation Indeed; that's the "rule" I imagine most English-speakers end up absorbing (even though it's not actually a rule in Spanish, it's just a mistaken generalization).

Comment: @JustinLardinois I always figured it came from Italian, where it doesn't have the accent either. Is it a Spanish word too?

Comment: @Draconis https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fort My takeaway is English loans _forte_ from two sources: French, to refer to abstract strength, and Italian, to refer to playing music loudly. It seems like most Romance languages have this word, variously having one of those meanings, or physical strength, or actual fortified structures, or a combination of the four.

Comment: @Draconis Habañero is a better example instead. Though influence with jalapeño is possible.

Comment: My favorite form of overcorrection is the [Metal-Ümlaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_umlaut). Funny for a native German speaker, because phonetically these diacritics have the exact opposite effect than they are meant to have.

Comment: @JustinLardinois But the stress is on the "for" both in French and Italian

Comment: @Philipp I wouldn't call metal umlauts overcorrection. They're a deliberate stylistic/branding choice.

Answer (score 14):

I was going to propose Julius Klaproth, in his 1823 book [*Asia Polyglotta*](https://ia800700.us.archive.org/12/items/asiapolyglotta01klapgoog/asiapolyglotta01klapgoog.pdf). He notates the difference between ك and ق as *k* versus *q*. In earlier works such as Hamer 1806 [*Ancient alphabets*](https://archive.org/details/ancientalphabet00conggoog/page/n6) 
both were represented as "k" with a note that [q] ق is "hard".
However, I see that 
Christian Ravis 1649 in [*A discourse of the orientall tongues : viz. Ebrew, Samaritan, Calde, Syriac, Arabic, and Ethiopic together with a generall grammer for the said tongues*](https://cbj.jhi.pl/documents/119483/54/) p. 96 or 97 (in the "General grammar" part) notates the kaf / qaf distinction with *k* versus *q* as well. 
Subsequently, it emerged that Otho Gualtperius 1590 in [Grammatica linguae sanctae](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=ZjY8AAAAcAAJ&hl=en&pg=GBS.PP30) described the analogous Hebrew kaph / qoph distinction as kaph *c,ch* (=[k,x]) versus  qoph "q or k". It is worth noting that the letter "q" itself [derives historically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q#History) from and still resembles the [Semitic letter qoph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qoph), which represented a Semitic sound that was either [q] or [k'] and is [q] in Arabic.

So at this point I would say that it is unknown who first devised that convention.

Comment: This is definitely going off on a tangent, but if the use of *Q* for a uvular dates back to 1590, I wonder how old it actually is? For example did any Classical-era Roman authors use *Q* for the Phoenician or Punic uvular? I just [asked about that](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/12570/406) on another site, if you have any insights.

Answer (score 13):

The answer to this question has multiple layers. [Draconis](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/33694) has already noted that the two sounds are distinct (phonemic) in Arabic and [user6726](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/33695) has added that the convention of writing one using *k* and the other using *q* dates back quite a number of centuries. But why does the Latin alphabet even have this ‘spare letter’ (Draconis) q that turns out to be nigh perfect to write a different, k-like sound?

Much of my answer is sourced from a German video on the history of Q in the German [Belles Lettres blog](https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/schrift/buchstabe-q-kentum-satem.php). Sadly, I don’t know of a translation of the entire video. But the author explores the history of why the letter Q exists in current German, why it existed in Old German and where it came from. The trivial answer to why do we have Q is that we inherited it from Latin, but why does Latin have it? Latin in turn borrowed the letter from Etruscan and initially used it somewhat unsystematically until the current convention of orthographic distinction emerged in which certain words are written with qu and most other /k/ sounds were written with c (cu contrasting with qu). Etruscan had a similar convention whereby certain vowels (u) were preceded by Q (their letter name being *Koppa*), others by K and others again by what the Romans would take over as C.

But why did Etruscan have three symbols for one sound? Well, all three were borrowed from one of the Ancient Greek alphabets with C actually being Greek gamma (Etruscans did not have voiced stops) and two Greek letters for the /k/ sound. However, shortly after the Etruscans borrowed the alphabet, Greek stopped using the kappa/koppa distinction altogether, most likely because there was no significant gain. The video I mentioned states that a number of /k/ sounds in Greek – that were typically spelt with koppa – migrated to /t/ sounds and others but for all intents and purposes we might just assume intelligent design and removal of clutter.

But if the Greeks had a letter Koppa that was nothing but clutter, why did they have it? Well, the Greek alphabet itself had been copied from the Phoenician alphabet. While Latin, Greek and German (and English) are Indo-European languages (and Etruscan, while not being Indo-European, has a debated origin as far as I’m aware), Phoenician is actually a Semitic language closely related to Hebrew and less closely to – you guessed it – Arabic. All these Semitic languages already had a k/q distinction (as in they had two phonemic consonants) and so it only made sense that alphabet systems (or abjad systems) designed to write these languages came up with two different letters for the two different sounds. The Phoenician alphabet is indeed among the oldest alphabets. So even if there had been some other convention to distinguish between the two Arabic *k* sounds in writing, it would make much more sense ‘etymologically’ to completely discard whatever else exists and use the k/q convention instead.

And why does ‘a lot of Q’ look Arabic when Hebrew has the same sound distinction? (Phoenician and most other Semitic languages are extinct and the ones that aren’t are minor, but in the western world one has a non-neglegible chance to come in contact with Hebrew names.) At some point before Hebrew as a language was revived, the k/q distinction was lost. As Hebrew became a purely liturgical language and Jews started using the native languages of the diaspora countries they were in, a lot of them no longer lived in a place that distinguished k and q phonemically so nowadays both Hebrew letters have the same pronunciation which is typically transliterated as *K* (Note: the Hebrew letter corresponding to K can also be pronounced as *kh*, which in itself is a separate orthographic and transliteration issue). This leaves Arabic as the last significant Semitic language to distinguish a k and a q sound.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "significant" Semitic languages, but k and q are distinguished in Amharic and the other Ethio-Semitic languages, in Mehri and other Modern South Arabian  languages, modern Aramaic languages, and even in the eastern (Mizrahi and Yemeni) reading tradition of Hebrew.

Comment: @fdb "even in the eastern (Mizrahi and Yemeni) reading tradition of Hebrew". Unfortunately, that dialect is dying out and is now almost purely found in liturgical pronounciation. In everyday speech, it's almost never used.

Comment: @fdb Thanks for prompting me to do further research. When I wrote k and q, I explicitly thought of /k/ and /q/; Amharic seems to use /kʼ/ (an ejective). But researching that, I found out that not all varieties of Arabic use /q/ (although Standard Modern Arabic apparantly does)! As for ‘significant’: yes, that’s a weasel word.